# Setting EditText in an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, layout-inflater

I have created a Custom AlertDialog and I'm trying to set text for EditTexts. I have tried following

```
public class CheckListDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private View view;

    public CheckListDialog(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public AlertDialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();    

        View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_checklist, null);

        EditText etCost = (EditText) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.etCost);
        EditText etOdoReading = (EditText) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.etOdometer);
        etOdoReading.setText("bla");
        etCost.setText("tada");

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(Reminders.this, android.R.color.transparent));
         builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_checklist, null))
               .setTitle("jaja")
               .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                   }
               });      
        return builder.create();
        }
    }
```

The EditTexts are empty and does not contain the values. How can i fix this?

Comment: you are inflating the layout again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_checklist, null))
```

with

```
builder.setView(dialogLayout)
```

You're modifying the edittexts in one layout and then inflating a new layout for the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

For such operations you have to use a custom layout to inflate into the **CheckListDialog**  class of yours. [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) will provide you complete freedom to customize your dialog as per your requirement.

You can refer to this [tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.sg/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html)